# Find the letters in a python list that follow each other most frequently

Tags: python

I have a python list like this one:

```
List = [s,b,s,d,h,a,h,e,h,a]
```

Is there a easy way to find out which letters follow each other most frequently.

In my list:

```
h,a = 2x
```

It would be also very cool to have a complete table of which letters follow which how often. But I am not sure how to tackle this

```
  b d a e
s 1 1
h     2 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and feed it letter pairs:

```
from collections import Counter

pair_counts = Counter(zip(List, List[1:]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> List = ['s', 'b' , 's', 'd', 'h', 'a', 'h', 'e', 'h', 'a']
>>> pair_counts = Counter(zip(List, List[1:]))
>>> pair_counts.most_common()
[(('h', 'a'), 2), (('d', 'h'), 1), (('s', 'b'), 1), (('s', 'd'), 1), (('b', 's'), 1), (('h', 'e'), 1), (('a', 'h'), 1), (('e', 'h'), 1)]
>>> pair_counts.most_common(1)
[(('h', 'a'), 2)]
```

The counter can also be used to produce your table:

```
values = sorted(set(List))
colwidth = len(str(pair_counts.most_common(1)[0][1]))
row_template = '{} ' + ' '.join(['{:>{colwidth}}'] * len(values))
print row_template.format(' ', colwidth=colwidth, *values)
for a in values:
    print row_template.format(a, colwidth=colwidth, *(
        pair_counts.get((a, b), '') for b in values))
```

which produces:

```
  a b d e h s
a         1  
b           1
d         1  
e         1  
h 2     1    
s   1 1
```

Comment: `Counter(zip(List1, List1[1:]))` will do the same job

Comment: Mega awesome. Thanks a million. Works excatly as I wanted

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the followed pairs with those frequency:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c= Counter(zip(l,l[1:]))
Counter({('h', 'a'): 2, ('d', 'h'): 1, ('s', 'b'): 1, ('s', 'd'): 1, ('b', 's'): 1, ('h', 'e'): 1, ('a', 'h'): 1, ('e', 'h'): 1})
```

And then with `most_common` method you can get the most common pair :

```
>>> c.most_common(1)
[(('h', 'a'), 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of generating the table you want (but it doesn't use `Counter`):

```
s = 'sbsdhaheha'

pairs = {}
for i,l in enumerate(s[:-1]):
    try:
        pairs[l + s[i+1]] += 1
    except KeyError:
        pairs[l + s[i+1]] = 1

l2s = sorted(set(pair[1] for pair in pairs))
print(' ', ' '.join(l2s))
for l1 in sorted(set(pair[0] for pair in pairs)):
    row = []
    for l2 in l2s:
        try:
            row.append(str(pairs[l1+l2]))
        except KeyError:
            row.append(' ')
    print(l1, ' '.join(row))
```

Output:

```
  a b d e h s
a         1  
b           1
d         1  
e         1  
h 2     1    
s   1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid building a new list you can use `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
l = ["s", "b", "s", "d", "h", "a", "h", "e", "h", "a"]
Counter(zip(l, islice(l, 1, None))).most_common()
```

If you are using python2 use izip:

```
from itertools import islice, izip   
Counter(izip(l, islice(l, 1, None))).most_common()
```